# How to write Espresso UI Test for Activity loading a Fragment with recycle View

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm getting start with Espresso, I have question regarding how to write this test, please help me to get a better idea or point resource which help me to get start

```
My applicaitn 
WelComeAcitivty -> this inlucde a button (LoadReceipe) When click on this it will load ReceipeListActivity

RecipeListActivity-> this acitivty show a fragment (RecepieFragmet built using RecyleView)

When you click on recipe item it will load another activity (ReceipeDetailActivity which also showing data in a fragment)

RecyleViewAdapter show Recipe Image and ReceipeTitle ( Imageview & textView)

ReceipeDetailActivity-> this activity hold a fragment and display detail of the receipe Fragment contains IamgeView receipeImage/TextView TitleOf Receipe/TextView Details of Cooking instruction
```

My questions?
1) How do I write an Espresso UI test to validate ReceipeList-fragment 
 is it display the data properly?  display text and images properly?. 
if the image is can't load display proper placeholder image?

2) how do I validate the item click event to load the correct detail view?

3) if there is  no data to show an  Empty view (FrameLayout with a text view "showing no data")

4)if there is network error show retry view? RetryView contain a TextVew and Button (Tapping on the button retry the load recipe network call)

Comment: I have the same issues here, but I would say please make your question more specific , still it is too general to say if the data is shown properly...
like, if the text view in the first and last cell index matches the "correct text" ?